# Why can't we use hard coded or initialize a value in Struct C++?

Tags: c++, struct

```
struct tester 
{
    int pt;
    int bt=25;  <--- this lines gives an error why ?
} one;
```

Comment: You can, you just need to be using C++11 or newer.

Comment: This can be done in C++11. If you want default values, why not look at `constructors`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in C++11. You just have to enable the compile option in gcc or clang, in MSVC 2012+ it is enabled by default.

```
struct tester 
{
    int pt{0};
    int bt{25}; 
} one;
```

If you have to stick with old C++, then you need a constructor as 
shown in other replies

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do that in versions c++11 or above. In case you need to use your current version itself you should use a constructor ( hoping you know what a constructor is, if not just google it )

This is how your code should look like

```
struct tester 
{
    int pt;
    int bt;
    tester() : bt(25)   // Initializer list
} one;
```

Alternatively

```
struct tester 
{
    int pt;
    int bt;
    tester()
      {
          bt=25;
      }
} one;
```

Comment: In the coding examples you gave, you should in fact swap them! Ideally the initializer list should be the first choice (which is mentioned as alternative), followed by the assignment in constructor.

Comment: In fact, there is no reason to use the (new) second "alternative".

Comment: I just provided as many possible codes as i could think of so that the person who asked this question can learn as much as possible.

Comment: @ArunA.S: Most students learn poorly from code without explanation. In particular, if you provide two forms, you **should** explain the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use initializer list as much as possible.

Initializer list chooses the best-match constructor for the object, which is fundamentally different from assignment.

```
#include<valarray>

    struct tester 
    {
        std::valarray<int> pt;
        const std::valarray<int> bt;
        tester() : pt(25) // Initialize pt to an valarray with space for
                          // 25 elements, whose values are uninitialized.
                          // Works well but may be confusing to most 
                          // people.
                  , bt(0, 25)   // initialize bt to an valarray of 25 zeros
    }
```